# One time login through Facebook in iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook-login

I have a app which has a login option which is only through the Facebook account. But when I run the app in simulator it always ask for login again and again when I am going to run my app. I want to show the main view if user is already logged in through the Facebook and when user delete the app and install again then user has to log in again to the app.

Comment: I suggest you to check this is real device.

Comment: If you want to save anything permanently(in keychain), even if user deletes the app, then follow this blog url:- http://www.programmingcrew.in/2015/08/save-value-in-keychain-ios-application.html

Comment: should it works on simulator @pkc456

Comment: Yes @shahinaliagharia.

Answer (score 0):

You should be saving a single sign on token? The simulator will fallback to 0Auth and may not be realistic, but it should remember it none the less.

Which version of the FaceBook SDK are you using?

Comment: I am using v4.4 @Mitchell Currie

Comment: From memory, it is your responsibility to save SSO tokens from Facebook. i.e. Facebook will log you in but its your job to check that the session is saved and linked against your own API or accounts

Comment: i.e. once you are logged in, you stay logged in and check if the session is still valid